# How security metrics are verified in testing phase?

Tags: architecture, requirements, enterprise-architecture, quality-attributes, non-functional

I am required to analyze and make an architecture of an application. While analyzing the requirements I find, in my system user personally identifiable information (PII) confidentiality is a very sensitive quality requirement and it must be taken to the NFR ([non functional requirement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement)) section. NFR requires that all the responses should have measurable equation which is used by tester in verification phase.

I am new in this area and facing hurdle for preparing data security related measure and their allowance limit. I prepared the NFR table as below and I am afraid that might not be proper way because, in verification phase it will be tough for tester to verify this requirement.

[image]

So, the question is, how usually data confidentiality and security attribute measures and allowance limits are set by architects for such software verification phase by testers?

Comment: So is it OK if I do 1,000,000 failed attacks followed by 10 attacks which leak your entire database?

Comment: @PhilipKendall: No system is totally secure.  It's like trying to provide mathematical proof that your system works; there is no such thing.

Comment: @PhilipKendall the term attack is a very complex stuff here due to nature of it and required environment. Linear test cases cannot make us assured that the system is secured even though all pass. That's why the question and it is really a tough analysis for me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's the point I was trying to make. I'll be less subtle next time :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already surmised, a metric like "Attack Success Rate <= 0.001%" isn't a particularly useful test metric for an acceptance text.

Have a look at [this page](https://nhsconnect.github.io/gpconnect/development_api_non_functional_requirements.html#security).  It says:

> ## Non-functional requirements
>
> ### Security
>
> Provider systems SHALL resist unauthorised, accidental or unintended usage and provide access only to legitimate users.
> Please refer to the [Security guidance page](https://nhsconnect.github.io/gpconnect/development_api_security_guidance.html#security-testing) for technical details.

Now, of course, that's *not* a testable requirement; it is a wish.  However, if you go to the Security guidance page that is linked there, you will find (among other things) this:

> ## Secure connection negotiation
>
> #### Provider systems:
>
> - SHALL only accept connections from the Spine Secure Proxy (SSP)
> - SHALL authenticate the SSP prior to responding to any requests using    its client certificate
> - SHALL only permit approved supported ciphers to be utilised
> - SHALL only accept encrypted connections and drop connection attempts    presented over insecure protocols
> - SHALL only accept requests for its allocated address space identifier    (ASID), as specified by the Ssp-To header on its
>   matching endpoint    URL
> - SHALL check that the Ssp-InteractionID value is consistent with the    endpoint being requested
> - SHALL check for the presence of all SSP headers
> - SHALL check that an authorization bearer token is present and    correctly formed
> - MAY authorise access to API endpoints through examining acceptable    values in the JSON Web Tokens (JWT) requested_scope claim
> - SHALL risk-manage the security of the endpoints of the Transport    Layer Security (TLS) communications, so as to prevent inappropriate  risks (for example, audit logging of the GET parameters into an unprotected audit log)

Ah, now we're getting somewhere.  For the most part, these *are* testable requirements.  Not only are they specific and testable, they also provide a detailed outline of your security strategy.

Comment: My architecture documents require a tabular representation of quality scenarios with allowance. You are essentially recommending splitting this security requirement into several checklists. Is that the standard process for evaluating security concerns? Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: "Security" is inherently multi-faceted. That means that requirements are multi-faceted; hence, multiple checklists with multiple dimensions.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan: If there are "standards" involved here, they are the ones embodied in the specific requirements, such as "SHALL only accept connections from the Spine Secure Proxy (SSP)".  The point here is that the specific requirements are *testable.*  If your suits need a metric, then assign points to each specific requirement, add them all up and create a score.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How is my question an "exact duplicate" of the previous question? In your comment to me, you said that the question I posed in my comment was different from the one I originally asked, so I posted a new one in a new thread. This is very inconsistent to me.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I took pains to make sure in the new question that I wanted to know how to add "some" type annotations. My question was definitely not an "exact duplicate."

Comment: @Sid: I hear what you're saying, but your new question is not materially different from your original one.  Fundamentally, the problem is that, in Python, running the program is the best way to find these types.  Find a static analyzer that knows how to do what you want, or write one yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> NFR requires that all the responses should have measurable equation which is used by tester in verification phase.

I thinking this is probably the root cause of your issue. Some problems are just hard, and can't easily be reduced to a simple metric.

If your business truly cares about protecting its users' PII, the best thing to do is almost certainly to get it tested by a professional penetration testing service, and then set the metric to something like "all security vulnerabilities above trivial threat level have been resolved".

Comment: Who defines the term “trivial threat level”? Whats the measurable scale?

Comment: Stop trying to reduce everything to a quantifiable number. The world isn't like that, sometimes you just have to use the best judgement of your trusted domain experts.